# Azure Devops Pipelines - Getting Mapping not allowed on YML template

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've created a steps yml to avoid repeating steps on each task and looks like this:

```
#azure-pipelines.yml
jobs:   
  - job: VS2019 
    pool:
       name: VS2019
    steps:
    - template: steps.yml   

#steps.yml
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet build'
    inputs:
        projects: '**/*.sln'
        arguments: '--no-restore --configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
```

I get mapping not allowed on steps.yml line 3, col 16(displayName line)

I've checked the indentation and tried with other tasks first but same result

Comment: Dedent line 3 onwards by 1 level in steps.yml.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Umm, that way throws unexpected values

Comment: Sorry, i was indenting with tab. Thas was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was indenting wrongly with tabs instead of double spaces

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).